# Can i load the private photos with my webapp from facebook users?

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token

I have a website and use the login using facebook.
I want to do the following:

User comes to my web site - login with facebook - I read his facebook data and photography permits

For example:

```
{
    "id": "1"
    "name": "John English"
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "English"
    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/johnenglish"
    "username": "johnenglish"
    "gender": "male"
    "locale": "en_US"
     ....
}
```

and

```
{
    "id": "2"
    "name": "John English2"
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "English2"
    "link": "https://www.facebook.com/johnenglish2"
    "username": "johnenglish2"
    "gender": "male"
    "locale": "en_US"
     ....
}
```

Both users have a private photo. Can I load the private photos from user (id: 2) with my web application using javascript? Can you give me the example?

I've tried this:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                    FB.api('/USER-ID(USER ID 2)/photos?access_token=' + accessToken, function(response) {

            //A user access token is required to request this resource.


                    });



                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

                } else {
                }
            });
```

Error: A user access token is required to request this resource.

Comment: On first glance, have you got a typo?  `"link": "https://www.facebook.com/johenglish"` should that be  `"link": "https://www.facebook.com/johnenglish"` ?

Comment: This is only for example. I want to load the private photos from another users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you requested the right permissions when you gained your access token? I don't know how to do it in JS, but you have to tell facebook, that you want you get access to the photos. As I do not work with JS, I request my access token via an URL (see Point 1 here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/devices/). In the parameter "scope" you can add the permissions you want to have ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/). Here, you add "&scope=user_photos" (without quotation marks) to the URL.

Comment: I have the scope: 'email user_photos user_birthday' 
I don't know how can i load the private photos from another user. I'm user with ID:1. Can i load the private photos from user with id 2 using my webapp?

Answer (score -1):

OK, now I understand your question.

I assume that you already found out the ID of the User 2. I am sorry but I can still not show you how to do it in JS. Though, it may help.

At first, I forgot one permission, you need `friends_photos` in scope, too.

You now call: http://graph.facebook.com/FRIEND_ID/albums/?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN.

Type it into your browser, so that you know what I mean: You parse that output and find ids of the albums of your friend.

You get to that album via: http://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN.

You will find an entry named `cover_photo` in your output.

Call: http://graph.facebook.com/COVER_PHOTO_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN and you get access to that photo.

You may now download it via http://graph.facebook.com/COVER_PHOTO_ID/picture?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN.

Use the URL given in `paging` -> `next` to move on to the following photos. It is much easier to follow these steps with a picture in mind, consider that [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).